# Jenkins pipeline with multiple triggers not triggering correctly

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-job-dsl

I have a jenkins pipleine which has two triggers one for pollSCM and the other is a cron job to run every Tuesday and Thursday at 6 pm EST. I configured it as follows

```
triggers {
        pollSCM('H/5 * * * *')
        cron('00 18 * * 2,4')
    }
```

I followed the document [here](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/syntax/#triggers) to set up the trigger. The pollSCM trigger works correctly. But the cron trigger, instead of triggering the build at 6 pm EST. Its trigerring at 2 pm EST. Why is this happening?

[image: Jenkins image]

Comment: Time defaults are UTC ...? Also, you did not specify TZ.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding TZ (timezone) in **Build periodically** under **Build Triggers**, helped to trigger the pipeline at 6 pm EST on Tuesday and Thursday.

```
TZ=America/New_York
00 18 * * 2,4
```

[image]